# If I apply oil on my hair then is my ablution valid or not?

Tags: fiqh, wudu, taharah, hair

If I apply oil on my hair then is my ablution valid or not?

I've searched this from 3 to 4 days but I can't find a proper answer which satisfy me.

Answer (score -2):

yes your ablution is ok. because it is said in the Quran

(4:3) O you who have believed, when you rise to [perform] prayer, wash your faces and your forearms to the elbows and wipe over your heads and wash your feet to the ankles.

it is clear that it does not matter what you put on your hair

Comment: How come it is clear? I don't see how consider elaborating. See [answer].

Comment: @Sassir because you can't tell wipe over heads and not mention that there must be nothing on the hair,  one part does not make sense without the other.  so this is why it is clear.