# Is ablution performed correct when a person wear an oil on a head?

Tags: fiqh, wudu, hair

I search and in a Quran (Holy Book of Muslims) I find this Ayat.

(4:3) "O you who have believed, when you rise to [perform] prayer, wash your faces and your forearms to the elbows and wipe over your heads and wash your feet to the ankles."

Here WIPE OVER YOUR HEADS means massah. But massah in that condition is correct when water reach our hairs. When the oil is act as a barrier on our heads same as nail polish act as barrier on our nails and water could not reach nails and than ablution is not perform correct by this.

Comment: Related post https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/53196/13438

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ablution is valid. In a similar situation where a pair of socks is put on, the one will have to wipe over it during the ablution, if there has been a prior ablution before putting on the socks. The bottom line is that, the Holy Qur'an mentioned "wash" but here we "wiped ", yet the Salat is Valid.
It is also the same in the case of turban.... The Salat of the one who put oil on his head is valid.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the ablution is correct and valid. This is because when you put oil on your hair the oil becomes part of hair.  When women dye their hair the hair-dye becomes part of hair. And when one wears nail polish the nail polist is part of nails so she does not have to remove the nail polish for ablution.